# Creating a schematic symbol in LTspice

Tags: schematics, ltspice, symbol

I use LTspice XVII on macOS. I want to create a symbol from a schematic so that I can instantiate that symbol wherever I want. I tried [this tutorial](https://www.ieee.li/pdf/viewgraphs/ltspice_creating_a_schematic_symbol.pdf) but I can't get it working.

Any help?

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: Have you tried the built-in help? For example `LTspice > Schematic Capture > ...`.

Comment: This video worked for me a while back when I needed to do the same; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XW1b71gfvlo it is very simple, just open a new schematic, draw the schematic of the subcircuit, then go to "Hierarchy" -> "Create a New Symbol", the symbol editor opens, draw your symbol, save and close..

Comment: @ThePhoton When I create my schematic and I right-click to select Hierarchy>Open this sheet's symbol... The symbol is not created in the AutoGenerated folder of the default parts path of LTSpice. Besides, if I take a look at the symbol as a plain text file, I don't see any reference to my schematic.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Yes, it was unhelpful.

Comment: @Vinzent I get stuck with the video because I can't change the default path of the parts library in macOS.

Comment: @dpalo What video? You're linking to a `.pdf`, and it says *exactly* what's in the manual, only with more pretty pictures and arrows you can't miss.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I meant the video that Vinzent linked. The PDF I linked covers the process in LTSpice for Windows. There must be some differences in macOS because if I take my schematic with ports, create a symbol from it, I instantiate that symbol from a second schematic *in the same folder*, and I try to simulate, an error arises ("Unknown subcircuit called in: ...")

Comment: @dpalo And have you tried editing the symbol? When you get there, press `CTRL+A` and change the `Model` line to suit you. Well, `CTRL+A` works on Windows, or in Wine on Linux, not sure about Mac. But you should be able to edit the path.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Sure, I added the name of the schematic (`mySchem.asc`) to the `ModelFile` field in the Attribute editor. Same problem.

Comment: @dpalo Why would you add your *schematic* to the `ModelFile`? Is that what the `.pdf` says?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I only have the schematic that I want to attach to a symbol and the netlist of the schematic. I tried adding both to the `ModelFile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a choice to make:

1. Create a symbol that ***can only be used in the same folder as the main schematic***. That means a *hierarchical* design, which means you can link that symbol to a **schematic**. In this case, when editing the symbol, its attribute `Symbol Type` must be of the type `block`, and in any of the `Value`, `Value2`, `SpiceLine`, and `SpiceLine2` lines there must be only parameters, if there are any, while the rest of the lines must be empty. This is an example:

[image: sa]

The `SpiceLine` with `f={f}` is optional, it depends on the current symbol which needs that. If yours also needs some parameters, then feel free to add some, otherwise the lines stay empty.

2. Create a symbol that can ***"instantiated wherever you want"***, including the same folder as the main schematic. This means that the symbol ***must be*** for either a **subcircuit** (`.subckt` definition), or a **model** (`.model` definition). In this case, the `Symbol Type` in the "Symbol Attribute Editor" must be of type `cell`.

[Everything I said here, and more, is explained both in the manual, and in the link ***you posted***, in detail.](https://www.ieee.li/pdf/viewgraphs/ltspice_creating_a_schematic_symbol.pdf) All you have to do is make up your mind about **what do you want that symbol for** (hierarchical design, or else), and *read carefully* that document.

Comment: In LTSpice for macOS, the `Symbol Type` is not visible in the Symbol Attribute Editor window. Anyway, I manage to create symbols that can be instantiated anywhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In LTSpice, in the window and tab of your schematic file, click the "Hierarchy" tab at the top, then from the options there, select the "Create a new symbol" option.